# Manipulating "Save PDF File As" function created by Adobe Reader XI Pro add-on

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

First of all - I have been searching everywhere and non of the solutions I have found have fit for my problem.

Basically I am creating a bookkeeping program and everything is working perfect. After alot of time in developing it is almost finished, but now I have run into a big problem.

**What the program wants to do?**

The program wants to print a salary report file created by it by sending it to a printer "Adobe PDF" which creates a pdf AND  EVERYTHING HERE IS WORKING FINE. But now the program opens a new window called "Save As PDF", where I need to insert the name of the file and press enter. I wrote code for it, but the code does not work although the window is activated. :/

And here is my code sample for the print button, where "CreateReceipt" just draws all the text into the pdf.

```
private void palgalipik_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
        printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Adobe PDF";
        printDialog.Document = printDocument;    
        printDocument.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(CreateReceipt);
        printDocument.Print();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500);
        SendKeys.SendWait(töötajanimi1.Text + "(" + palgaperiood.Text + ")");
        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
    }
```

**TL;DR problem**
Need to insert insert a string into "Save PDF File As" dialog box and click ENTER aka "Save". Code should do it, but doesnt - what is the problem?

**NB! I want to use Adobe Reader XI Pro, because all computer in the company have it so it is alot better than starting to do it with iTextSharp or other alternatives.**

Thanks in advance and ask me if anything is still blurry about my question!

Comment: There is no software called "Adobe Reader XI Pro". There is (the free of charge) Adobe Reader XI, and there is (the paying) Adobe Acrobat XI Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use APIs to create a PDF instead of printer:

http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/

or

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Comment: At the moment I have already given up on manipulation and am coding itextsharp API to do the job for me, but I am still wondering if it would be possible to make program push down the buttons without user interference. Thanks for your opinion anyway!

Comment: -1. A link-only answer is not useful and is discouraged in StackOverflow, because the link could go offline.

Comment: My answer is to use APIs instead of his current method. Links are examples.